Explicit definition of the universal property of a subobject classifier by a universal morphism
I'm trying to give a description of the universal property of the subobject classifier explicitly in terms of a universal morphism to/from some functor (i.e, for $\Omega ∈ ob(C)$, I would like to find a functor $F:C→D$, an object $X ∈ ob(D)$, such that the existence of a universal morphism $u:F(\Omega)→X$ or $X→F(\Omega)$ is equivalent to $\Omega$ being a classifier). I am having difficulty finding the appropriate choices to use, so any hint here is appreciated. Thanks!
Edit: This question was asked under the assumption that the defining property of the subobject classifier is in fact a universal property in this sense (and is regarded as such). I have come to realise that I don't have a source for this, and it is probably false. Apologies for the misleading question!

See also this question and answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128580/subobject-classifier-of-c-is-the-same-as-the-terminal-object-of-d/4128612#4128612

Universal morphisms are an equivalent characterisation of adjoint functors: $L : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ has a right adjoint if every object $D : \mathcal{D}$ has a universal morphism $f : L(X) \to D$ which is initial in the comma category $L \downarrow \mathcal{D}$.
If we wanted to rephrase the representability of the subobject presheaf $\mathrm{Sub}(-)$ in terms of adjoints, we could go through terminal objects: a presheaf is representable if its category of elements has a terminal object, and a terminal object in $\int^X \mathrm{Sub}(X)$ is a right adjoint to the unique functor $! : \int^X \mathrm{Sub}(X) \to 1$. So, a subobject classifier is a universal morphism $f : !(S) = \star \to \star$ such that every other morphism $g : !(T) = \star \to \star$ factors through $f$ via a unique morphism $h : T \to S$. Since $f$ and $g$ are morphisms in the terminal category, they are irrelevant, so we are left with just the objects: rephrasing and unfolding definitions, we get a universal subobject $S = (1 \hookrightarrow \Omega)$ such that every other subobject $T = (X \hookrightarrow Y)$ arises uniquely as a pullback of $S$.
In other words, we gain absolutely nothing from this perspective: it just makes things more verbose.
Another way to say this is that universal morphisms are about (co)freely adding some structure to an object $D$, but a subobject classifier isn't really a structure on a particular object, so that approach doesn't really work.

Universal properties more generally can be derived as a part of a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ being representable.  Namely, if we have some object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $F \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X, {-})$, then according to Yoneda's lemma, we take the inverse image of $\operatorname{id}_X$, which is an element $x_0 \in F(X)$, to be a universal object.  The universal property of this object, which we also get from Yoneda's lemma, is: for any object $Y$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and any element $y \in F(Y)$, there exists a unique morphism $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y)$ such that $F(f)(x_0) = y$.
In the case of subobject classifier on a well-powered category $\mathcal{C}$ with pullbacks, that is precisely a representing object of the functor $\operatorname{Sub} : \mathcal{C}^{\operatorname{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$ which takes an object $X$ to the set of subobjects of $X$, and which acts on morphisms by taking pullbacks of subobjects.  According to the above, that functor is representable if and only if there exists an object $\Omega$ and a universal subobject $\mathsf{true} : \Omega_0 \hookrightarrow \Omega$, such that for any other object $X$ with subobject $X'$, there is a unique morphism $\chi_{X'} : X \to \Omega$ such that we get a cartesian square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} X' @>>> \Omega_0 \\
@VVV @VV \mathsf{true} V \\
X @> \chi_{X'} >> \Omega. \end{CD}$$
(And given this, we can show that $\Omega_0$ is necessarily a terminal object, so we might as well rename $\Omega_0$ to $1$, or in the case of a finitely complete category with a prenamed terminal object $1$, compose with the unique isomorphism $1 \to \Omega_0$ to get a morphism $1 \to \Omega$ which is also a universal subobject.)
So technically, in terms of your question, you could take $D := \mathsf{Set}$, $F := \operatorname{Sub} : C^{\operatorname{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$, and $X := \{ * \}$, and then use that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(\{ * \}, Y) \simeq Y$; but that's a bit of unnecessary extra noise.  Actually, in this specific case, you could also take $D := \mathsf{Poset}$ instead, and $X := (\{ * \}, {\le} := \{ (*, *) \})$; or similarly, take $D$ to be the category of semi-Heyting algebras (that's the fragment of Heyting algebras with operations $\top, \wedge, \rightarrow$); or in case $\mathcal{C}$ is a topos, you could take $D$ to be the category of Heyting algebras.
